# METEOR.JS update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier)

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to understand the parameters passed into this function in the allow deny rules of Meteor: 
update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier)

I have a book that says:
userId: The user Id of the current logged-in user who performs that update action
doc: The document from the database, without the proposed changes
fields: An array with field parameters that will be updated
modifier: The modifier the user passed to the update function, such as {$set: {'name.first': "Alice"}, $inc: {score: 1}}

So I'm trying to understand the parameters more and so I did this inside the method:

```
update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier){
  //User must be an admin

  console.log('inside allow update');
  console.log('userId = ' + userId);
  console.log('doc = ' + doc);
  console.log(doc.title);
  console.log('fields = ' + fields);
  console.log(fields[0]);
  console.log(fields.length);
  console.log('modifier = ' + modifier);

  return Meteor.user().roles.admin;
},
```

But for the doc and modifier I just get a [object Object] logged to the console.

So my questions are:
1.) what is [object Object]?

2.) it says doc is the document from the database and in my database I have the 'title' field...but when I do console.log(doc.title) I am getting undefined....so how am I suppose to use doc properly??? What is it used for inside this update method?

3.) How about the modifier object..how am I suppose to use it within this update method??? what is it useful for??

Thank you very much...

Comment: Don't try to add it to string, `console.log(fields)` will show you whole object, not just name `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

As @Sindis said, you should avoid concatenating objects onto strings.. so you can either do

```
console.log(doc);
```

or

```
console.log("the doc is ", doc);
```

instead of

```
console.log("the doc is " + doc);
```